# Why do the coefficients of all polynomials of degree at most $d$ as coordinates of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ lie in ${R}^{d+1}$'s unit sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces

Consider the coefficients of all polynomials of degree at most $d$ as coordinates of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.

Why would it suffice to suffices to assume that this vector lies in the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$? How would I show this to be true?

Comment: Or is statement false?

Comment: It seems pretty false.  Consider some polynomial $f(t)=10000\sum_{k=0}^d t^k$.  Viewed as coordinates of $\mathbb R^{d+1}$, this is $(10000,10000,...,10000)$ which is outside the unit sphere.  You could also construct MUCH more severe counterexamples.

Comment: But the polynomial is of degree $d$ and it's only in the coordinates of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.  Where did $n$ come from in your example?  
I'm pretty sure it's true.

Comment: Habit, I edited it to be "d" already I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the truthfulness your statement heavily depends on what you want to do with the polynomials.

A quite generic argument would be the following:

Suppose you have a polynomial $f$ (which is not constant zero) of degree at most $d$ with coefficients $(c_0,c_1,\ldots, c_d)$ (corresponding to powers of $x$). Now let $c := \max_{i=0,\ldots, d} |c_i|$ and define a new polynomial by $g(x) := 1/c \cdot f(x)$. Then the coefficients of $g$ are 
$$\left( \frac{c_0}{c} , \ldots , \frac{c_d}{c} \right)$$
which are all $\leq 1$ and $g$ has basically the same properties as $f$. More precisely, $g$ is just a downscaled version of $f$. So as long as you are not interested in actual values of $f$ but only 'what does the graph look like?', 'where are its roots?', 'is it irreducible?' and so forth, you can consider $g$ instead of $f$.

Comment: While that's true, at that point the "unit sphere" part seems pretty inconsequential, and you're really just saying something like "there's an ismorphism between $P_d(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb R^{d+1}$", which isn't too surprising.

Comment: What I want to do with this vector, ultimately, is use it to show that there is a constant $A_d \lt 0$ such that $\sup_{x∈[0,1]}{|p'(x)|} \leq A_d \sup_{x∈[0,1]}{|p(x)|}$.

That's what I want to do with it.

Comment: Fixed my comment.

Comment: @Mark Obviously, you are right. However, I don't think that one can assume that every person around here knows about projective spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to believe it's true, I will demonstrate it isn't.

Define the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^{d+1}=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^{d+1}\,\middle|\,|x|\leq 1\right\}$.  Assume the Euclidean norm, so $|x|=\sqrt{x\cdot x}$.

Denote the coefficients of a polynomial $f$ as $f_i$.  So $f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^df_kt^k$.  Let $\beta(f)=\max_{i\in\mathbb N}|f_i|$.  So, for any nonzero $f\in P_d(\mathbb R)$, we have that  $\beta(f)> 0$.

Now, take any nonzero polynomial $g$.  Define a new polynomial $g'=\frac{g}{\beta(g)}(1+\epsilon)$ (with $\epsilon>0$).  This is a "normalized" polynomial, so the maximum value of $|g_i'|$ is $(1+\epsilon)$.  So, with the summation notation we have that $g'(t)=\sum_{k=0}^d \frac{g_i}{\beta(g)}(1+\epsilon)t^k$.  Now, consider the vector in $\mathbb R^{d+1}$ corresponding with that polynomial.  Might as well call it $G'$.  So, $|G'|=\sqrt{G'\cdot G'}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{d+1}\left(\frac{g_k}{\beta(g)}(1+\epsilon)\right)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{(1+\epsilon)^2}{\beta(g)^2}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{d+1}(g_{k})^2}=\frac{(1+\epsilon)}{\beta(g)}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{d+1}g_k^2}$.  If we let $|g_i|$ be the value we chose with $\beta$ earlier, we get that $|G'|=\frac{(1+\epsilon)}{|g_i|}\sqrt{|g_i|^2+\sum_{k=1,k\neq i}^{d+1}g_k^2}$.

From this, we know that $|G'|\leq \frac{(1+\epsilon)}{|g_i|}\sqrt{|g_i|^2}=(1+\epsilon)$.  So, from any nonzero polynomial $g$, we can construct a polynomial $g'$ that has the property that $|G'|\geq (1+\epsilon)>1$, meaning it's outside of the unit sphere.